# React - Redux - Integrate Firebase Database in my App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux, react-redux

im making a simple portfolio using **react**, **redux** and **redux-thunk**.The Objective is to catch data from firebase and display it on my **trabalhos.js** component.

I don´t know how to pass the data to my component. Could some one help me ? thanks

Heres my **action**

```
import Firebase from 'firebase';
import { FETCH_DATA } from './types';

var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/database");

var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDi3f9pSGH833Hq3TBzibCK1SbPOheiGmE",
    authDomain: "portofoliofirebase.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://portofoliofirebase.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "portofoliofirebase.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "656734450041"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var data = firebase.database().ref();

export function fetchData(){
 return dispatch => {
    data.on('value', snapshot => {
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_DATA,
            payload: snapshot.val()
        });
    });
};
}
```

Heres my **Reducer**

```
import { FETCH_DATA } from '../actions/types';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
switch(action.type){
    case FETCH_DATA:
        return action.payload;      
}

return state;
}
```

Heres my **rootReducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import fetchReducer from './fetch_reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({

fetch: fetchReducer

});

export default rootReducer;
```

Heres my **trabalhos.js** component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';


class Trabalhos extends Component {

    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.fetchData();
    }

    renderList(){

        return(
            <li>

            </li>

        )
    }

    render(){
    return (

        <div>
            <div className="trabalhos">
                <div className="trabalhos_caixa">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xs-12">
                            <ul className="no_pad">
                                {this.renderList()}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}


function mapStateToProps(state){

return { fetch: state.fetch };

}



export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Trabalhos);
```

Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

First thing a good video for help you understand that just [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHJq5NOtNG4)

Now you have mapStateToProps on an object call fetch. Would be a better idea to change the name for something easier to follow like data etc. But this is a personal choice.

```
function mapStateToProps(state){

return { data: state.fetch };

}
```

Now you can access the props in the component like you did with everything. You use `this.props.fetch` or if you change the name `this.props.data` . I don't know what look like your data but a good thing to use is react [dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) so it's easy to see the props on each component.

The last thing would be to do the tutorial about redux [here](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux), this is free and an awesome resource from the creator of redux ;)

Hope that can help you.

Comment: thanks for the help ! If i console my action i can see the info that came from the database , so im getting the info in my reducer, now the difficult is to present that data on my component, im getting the error  -- Uncaught TypeError: this.props.fetch.map is not a function(…) -- can you help me ?

Comment: Surely cause the data is not an array but more an object. You need to console.log the data and figure out the way to handle this type. Inside your component just `console.log(this.props)` and let me know which kind of data is